# Sendmail To Multiple Users Without CC

Tags: email, sendmail

Hello everyone I was wondering if it's possible to use sendmail in a way that I can string multiple email addresses in the To: as such

```
From: sendmail
To: person01@gmail.com;person02@gmail.com
Subject: Did You Both Receive It?

I hope you did
```

Instead of using

```
From: sendmail
To: person01@gmail.com
Cc: person02@gmail.com
Subject: Did You Both Receive It?

I hope you did
```

Comment: Separate them with commas, not semicolon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To put multiple addresses on the `To:` or `Cc:` or `Bcc:` line, separate them by a comma (plus optional spaces). There are mail readers that allow typing a semicolon to separate addresses and show addresses separated by semicolons, but this is not standard syntax.

```
From: sendmail
To: person01@gmail.com, person02@gmail.com
Subject: Did You Both Receive It?
```

You can split the header onto multiple lines after the comma (and at some other places in the address, but this is trickier). The continuation line must start with at least one space or tab.

```
From: sendmail
To: person01@gmail.com,
    person02@gmail.com
Subject: Did You Both Receive It?
```

Comment: +1 I suspected there was something cleaner, like this... I learnt something today!

Comment: Sorry I never saw this until now, this did indeed solve my issue

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `To:` header several times. I was a little skeptical about it, but I just tried it on a SMTP server, and it accepted it.

So, instead of sending...

```
From: sendmail
To: person01@gmail.com
Cc: person02@gmail.com
Subject: Did You Both Receive It?

I hope you did
```

... you could send:

```
From: sendmail
To: person01@gmail.com
To: person02@gmail.com
Subject: Did You Both Receive It?

I hope you did
```

In my client (Thunderbird), the recipients appear together, as:

```
To person01 <person01@gmail.com>, person02 <person02@gmail.com>
```

and the source remains intact (the `To:`s were not transformed on the way) :

```
To: person01@gmail.com
To: person02@gmail.com
```

Now, since the SMTP server allowed me to send two `RCPT TO:` messages, I'm assuming `sendmail` would be able to do this as well. Probably something like...

```
$ sendmail "person01@gmail.com,person02@gmail.com" <<EOF
To: person01@gmail.com
To: person02@gmail.com
...

Your message.
EOF
```

Comment: Some servers allow multiple `To:` headers, but beware that this is not standard behavior: the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) states that `To:` and `Cc:` can occur at most once. I suspect that there are MTAs that ignore all but the first or last `To:` line.